# Reading specific number of lines from text file in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm using the following StreamReader to read from text file

```
string temp = fs.ReadToEnd ();
readlines[i] = temp;
```

I want to read a specific number of lines from the text file (let we say, from line number 1 until line number 300 only), then write the lines into one element of array. Could anyone help please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted. I up-voted it again to 0.

Comment: @ Helgi, Always that happens to me. I don't know what to say. Thanks for your kind action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tried with a simple text file.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("yourfile").Take(300);
readlines[i] = string.Join("-", lines);
```

Comment: If you are using .NET 4 or aboove, you should prefer ReadLines (rather than ReadAllLines) which won't actually read the lines you don't want http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: @Kek, yes you are right. Updating the answer, but now is identical to your own :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to skip n first lines and read p lines from there :

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).Skip(n).Take(p).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ReadLine` method and add a `counter` and increase it by line and when you hit 300 do a `break` out of the loop

Comment: its possible, but then i would read the whole file wich can have performance issues when the text file is big